# How to display one control over another

Tags: asp.net

I am generating asp.net project in which I want to put one control over another and make them visible true\false according to the list item selected from unordered list. I want to know how can I get which list item is selected from unordered list and how to place one control over other like what we can do easily in windows form.
Code for unordered list is:

```
     <ul id="nav" >
            <li class="srvlist"><a href="Default.aspx">Dashboard</a>
                <div class="sub1">
                <ul id="inner_nav">
                    <div class="arrow1"></div>
                    <li><a href="#">Recent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="srvlist"><a href="#">Statistics</a>
                <div class="sub1">
                <ul id="inner_nav">
                    <div class="arrow1"></div>
                    <li><a href="#">Opens</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clicks</a></li>                        
                    <li><a href="#">Bounces</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spams</a></li>                        
                    <li><a href="#">Unsubscribe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blocks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Invalid Ids</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Graph</a></li>                
            <li><a href="#">Compose</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: what you got wrong? have you googled for this? share you code.

Comment: I googled.. It said I will have to do it using css, but how?

Comment: ok, you have to share your code

Answer (score 0):

Keep both controls side by side, invisible control will automatically release that place for visible one.

Comment: Why you think so? just write 2 lines and varify, I have done it frequently

Answer (score 0):

Create two divisions , and put your control into each division !
In [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uwPGV/) , you can see how to overlap two division using `position:absolute;` .
You can change the visibility of each division like `yourDivID.Visible = true/false;` in code-behind !

And additionally , I suggest you to use `UserControl` for your requirement !
You have to make two `UserControl` and , you can bind this `UserControl` to the same `Content`
dynamically !

Comment: Thank you Zey.. I could make it overlap but how can I make one visible another invisible?

Comment: Thanks Zey.. I got it.. Can you please help me with which list item is selected from unorderes list?

Comment: I don't get what you said ! Can you tell me more detail ?

Comment: According to item selected from unordered list I want show and hide the controls. Showing and hiding of controls is done but I want to know how to obtain that which list item is selected.

Comment: You will need to add a runat="server" tag to access it from the code-behind.If you use a different control other than an <a> tag like <asp:HyperLink> or <asp:LinkButton>, then you can capture this selected information from your C# code behind !